# Optaplanner does not change planning variable

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am working on an optimisation problem with Optaplanner. I have the feeling that I have not designed my planning entity or variable correctly. Maybe someone would like to say what they think about the following case:

Entities:
In principle, it is a fairly simple problem. There are a lot of warehouses that store exactly one product and that can receive products or supply other warehouses on specified transport routes. Let's call them nodes.

```
class Node
   int upperBoundary
   int lowerBoundary
   int items
   String name
```

Each transport route can transport all products. You could think of the problem as a matrix or a tree. I have defined the cells of the matrix as planning entities. The planning variable is an integer value on the cell. Let's call them weighted edges. In my Solution Class is a `List<Edge> edges.`

```
   E1 E2 E3 ... En
 N1 1  0  0     2
 N2 3  1  3     1
 N3 0  1  0     0
... 
 Nn 1  1  0     0


@PlanningEntity
class WeightedEdge
   Node from
   Node to

   @PlanningVariable
   Integer items (nullable)

   int minCapacity
   int maxCapacity
```

In my example I now have about 450 weighted edges. All of them have minimum and maximum values. These are recognised correctly.

```
Node a min 0 max 40
Node b min 0 max 20 uws.
```

If I now run a benchmark, it shows me exactly the sum of the number ranges from the individual nodes as the "problem scale". In the example above it would be 60.

But the problem is that the planning variables have dependencies. It therefore makes a difference whether I enter 39 for a and 20 for b. Or 38 for a and 20 for b. This gives me 800 possibilities. Does anyone have an idea where the design error could be in this structure?

The Scoring Function aims to balance the Nodes, so that after the planning period their amount of items is between the upper and lower boundary. For that I am using the constraintProvider.

1. SoftScore = Sum of to many or to few items at each station through the whole network

--- Edit ---

As suggested, I changed the environment mode to FULL_ASSERT. With this config, the solver throws an error:

with this mode it throws an error. My undoMove is corrupted:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UndoMove corruption (1soft): the beforeMoveScore (-65init/0hard/0medium/-2412soft) is not the undoScore (-65init/0hard/0medium/-2411soft) which is the uncorruptedScore (-65init/0hard/0medium/-2411soft) of the workingSolution.
  1) Enable EnvironmentMode FULL_ASSERT (if you haven't already) to fail-faster in case there's a score corruption or variable listener corruption.
  2) Check the Move.createUndoMove(...) method of the moveClass (class org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove). The move (0 items -> 3 items) might have a corrupted undoMove (Undo(0 items -> 3 items)).
  3) Check your custom VariableListeners (if you have any) for shadow variables that are used by score constraints that could cause the scoreDifference (1soft).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertExpectedUndoMoveScore(AbstractScoreDirector.java:670)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.MoveThreadRunner.run(MoveThreadRunner.java:149)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    ... 4 more
```

--- Edit 2: Score over time Graph ---
[image: Edit 2: Score over time Graph]

--- Edit 3: Memory Consumption Graph ---
[image: Memory Consumption Graph]

Comment: What happens if you turn on environmentMode FULL_ASSERT and let it solve for much longer time?

Comment: with this mode it throws an error. My undoMove is corrupted (added it to the case description)

Comment: Suspicious is "The move (0 items -> 3 items) might have a corrupted undoMove (Undo(0 items -> 3 items)" Why are the move and the undo-move the same?

Comment: Ok, i had an issue in one of my constraints, where I used datetime.now. I removed this from calculation and it runs without errors. But my problem from the beginning ist still there. I found out, that my browser did not render the benchmark correct. Changes of the score are present but it its very fast (see an excel graph added to the description). Also suspicious is the memory consumption. After a while it just consumes more and more?

Comment: Also I have. a huge number of uninitialized variables after the constructions ((-688init/0hard/0medium/-996soft)). My planning variable can be null, but null would mean the same as 0. So transport nothing is possible in all cases. Should I try to set the value in advance? But this seems not as a valid solution for me.

Comment: After the construction heuristics, it is fine if you have hard constraints broken. However, the fact that you still have *uninitialized* entities is a problem - after the CH, that number should be zero. (It doesn't really matter if the variable is null - uninitialized means the CH did not even touch the entity.) How does your solver config look?

Comment: I found the solution of the misbehavior. I had a process to clean the solution space in before to reduce the problem size. If a edge is not possible to plan but is relevant for the calculation (for example the transport has been started, but it is not arrived), I pinned the planning variable. Some if them where null and so the CH could not initialize them. After deleting the not possible edges with zero planned items no uninitialized entities are left.

Comment: The only thing left ist the memory consumption. Is that behavior normal? I thought the memory after initializing the problem will not increase further. But as the graph in the question shows that is not the case. It takes 3 minutes to reach the point where the memory usage does not increase (or at least increase slower) anymore.

Comment: The memory use likely stopped growing because you hit the max heap size your JVM is configured to use. (See that it stopped around the 8G mark, which is a suspiciously "round" number.) This should also mean that at that point, GC started slowing your solver down considerably. This could indeed be a memory leak, or your dataset is so large that OP exceeds even 8G of heap for it. Without having executable code, it is difficult for me to be less vague.

Comment: Yes, I limited the memory size at 8gb. All I have are around 400 objects of the planning entity (edges) and 150 nodes . The planning variable is an integer. This should not use so much memory, right?